# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have created the following function:

```
def c_min(a,b):
    result= [x - y for x in a for y in b]
    min=np.min(result)
    return min
```

I have created a test file with two lists:

```
a=[1,2,3] and b=[4,5,6]
```

When I running the function I get the correct result.

However when I run the function in my initial code I have the aforementioned in the title error.
Have to be noted that the function in the initial code is applied in two arrays. One has size 1 and it is numpy.float64,the other 3 and it is numpy.ndarray. 
Why it can be applied to list and not in the arrays?

Comment: Can you post the inputs that are raising this error?

Comment: you can't iterate scalars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `a` and `b` need to be `numpy.ndarray`. If one of them is a scalar, the `for ... in ...`  construct will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the post using the `numpy.array`or `numpy.ndarray`the problem can be solved.